# Can't Add custom page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

In wordpress i create custom page

```
<?php /*custom page template*/?>
```

and add it by filezilla in `wp-content/themes/twentytwenty/templates` 
but when adding page from dashboard i can't find my custom page

Comment: What you are creating is a page template, not a new page per se. You need to add a new page under "Pages" and select your new template under "Page Attributes".

Comment: i can't find my new template under page attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ex:  your templates'name is custom

add  custom.php  in wp-content/themes/twentytwenty

and 
on top of custom.php add

```
<?php /* Template Name: custom */ ?>
```